# Why does Google Analytics attribute all Success Page completions to Stripe Checkout, and how to fix it?

Tags: google-analytics, stripe-payments

I have a problem with **google analytics** and **stripe checkout** where all goal completions are attributed to checkout.stripe.com, instead of the actual referring website.

I am using Google Analytics UA and have the Global site tag on all pages.  Then I have a goal to track the success page, which stripe checkout redirects to upon successful completion.

User flow:

1. Website visitor comes from one of the referral pages.
2. Then they click on the stripe checkout button, which takes them to a stripe hosted page.
3. On stripe hosted checkout page, enter payment info.
4. Upon successful payment, redirected to success.html (which is the goal being tracked in analytics).

So when a user goes to success.html, Google analytics attributes the goal completion to stripe checkout, instead of the website that referred them to my site in the first place.

Has anyone else experienced this?  Am I doing something wrong or is this just how Google Analytics works when using Stripe Checkout?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems like a GA configuration issue rather than Stripe. I'm not really familiar with GA, but if there's some way you can override the attribution, Stripe Checkout lets you set your `success_url` dynamically. For example, for each customer sent to Checkout, you could include the original referrer in the success URL they'd ultimately be sent to, in addition to getting the Checkout session ID in case you'd like to retrieve some session data (like metadata):

```
success_url: "http://example.com/success.html?original_referral=ref_123&session_id={CHECKOUT_SESSION_ID}",
```

https://stripe.com/docs/payments/checkout/custom-success-page#modify-success-url

Comment: Thank you for your help! I found the answer, it is Referral exclusion.  See page https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2795830?hl=en.  It even lists common use case of third-party payment processors

Comment: Ah, neat, good to know, thanks for sharing that back!

Answer (score 0):

not sure if you have solved this yet but you can block certain referral urls. Go to analytics go to admin> set up assistant > tag installation> click on your data stream > more tagging settings > list unwanted referrals> then from there just exclude the url you don't want tracked so in your case it's checkout.stripe.com